# OSX create temporary passwords

Tags: macos, passwords

I'm using OSX 10.11.2 and I have a script that already creates new users using `dscl`. I would like to assign new users **programmatically** a temporary password that is valid say for 24 hours and that I can distribute via email. The user should then login (e.g. SSH) within this grace time and be forced to change their password (`passwd`). The newly chosen password should not have an expiration date. If instead the temporary password expires, the user account should be automatically disabled.

I **do not want** to use any authentication server. All users are local.

I think this could be hacked with a crontab and reading the `passwordLastSetTime` from `dscl . -read /Users/<username> accountPolicyData`. But isn't there a simpler way?

Reading https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/18574/user-password-policies-on-non-ad-machines, I tried using `pwpolicy`, but somehow the simpler `DEPRECATED` options do not seem to be enforced by OSX. Also, due to my playing around with `pwpolicy`, local users can't change their own passwords anymore, they get `passwd: general failure`.

Reading https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/9559/password-expiration-warning-without-active-directory, `PasswordPolicyOptions` seems to be useful. Unfortunately `dscl . read /Users/<username> PasswordPolicyOption` returns `No such key: PasswordPolicyOptions`, possibly due to my earlier (disruptive) experiments with `pwpolicy`.

Does anyone have suggestions on how best to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: OSX has a command called pwpolicy that you may find interesting. Unfortunately documentation is very limited on how to use it. There is a reference in the man page about creating an XML plist of policies, and one of the policy rule is `policyAttributeNewPasswordRequiredTime - Time when a new password is required.` which may be what you need.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it is not entirely clear to me how one should use `policyAttributeNewPasswordRequiredTime`. In the end I implemented this feature with a script that parses `passwordlastSetTime` from `dscl . read /Users/<user> accountPolicyData`. A crontab just checks whether `passwordlastSetTime` has been changed and otherwise suspends the user using `pwpolicy -u <user> disableuser`. I also found out users cannot change their passwords with `passwd` if the field `dsAttrTypeNative:_writers_passwd <user>` is not set, see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/118081.